# Does any scripture give reasons for non-inclusion of Neem leaves in the list of 21 leaves for Ganapati puja?

Tags: scripture, ganapati

Today is Sri Ganapati chaturdhi.  After performing the puja, I got the following doubt.

The List of 21 types of leaves used for Ganesha puja, is as follows.  These [leaves are stated to have](http://lalithambanlr.blogspot.com/2010/09/happy-vinayaka-chaturdhi.html) medicinal values.

> 1.Shami Patra -- शमी , Telugu- Jammi

> 2.Bhringraj Patra - भृंगराज, Telugu- Guntakalagara
>
> 3.Bilva Patra- बेल , Telugu- Bilvam

> 4.Durva Patra- दूर्वा, Telugu - Garika

> 5.Ber Patra- बेर, Telugu - Regu

> 6.Datura Patra - धतूरा, Telugu- Ummetta
>
> 7.Tulasi Patra - तुलसी, Telugu- Tulasi

> 8. Sem Patra - सेम, Telugu - Chikkudu
> 9. Apamarga Patra- अपामार्ग , Telugu- Uttareni

> 10.Bhatakataiya Patra -भटकटैया,Telugu -Gurrapu gattaku.
>
> 11.Sindoor Patra - सिन्दूर,Telugu- Sindooram

> 12. Tej Patra - तेजपत्ता, Telugu -Talisapatri
> 13. Agastya Patra - अगस्त्य, Telugu -Avisa

> 14.Kaner Patra - कनेर,Telugu - Ganneru
>
> 15. Kadali Patra - केला पत्र, Telugu - Arati

> 16. Arka Patra - आक,Telugu - Jilledu
> 17. Arjuna Patra - अर्जुन वृक्ष, Telugu Tella maddi,Yerra maddi
> 18. Devdar Patra - देवदार,Telugu- Devadaru

> 19. Marua Patra - मरुआ,Telugu- Maruvam
> 20. Gandari Patra - गण्डारि पत्र, Telugu- Devakanchanamu
> 21. Ketaki Patra - केतकी, Telugu -Gedaga

---

If we closely observe the leaves pertaining to [Neem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azadirachta_indica) are missing in the above list.

Neem is stated to have a wide range of [medicinal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azadirachta_indica#Traditional_medicinal_use), widely available in India, and is being in use in India since long.

> Neem products are believed by Siddha and Ayurvedic practitioners to be
> anthelmintic, antifungal, antidiabetic, antibacterial, contraceptive,
> and sedative.

---

Does any scripture give reasons for **non-inclusion of Neem leaves** for Ganapati puja?