# Does any scripture recommend Tulasi leaves in Ganesha Puja on Ganesha Chaturthi?

Tags: ganesha, puja, tulasi

As per [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/42581/12304) post, Tulasi is included in leaves to be offered to Ganesha on Ganesha Chaturthi.

But, Tulasi is [prohibited](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3182/12304) in Ganesha puja on normal days.

Is there any scriptural basis which allows Tulasi in Ganesha puja on Ganesha Chaturthi?

Comment: Tulasi leaves are prohibited to be used in Ganesha Puja. So, I don't understand why it will be allowed on that particular day.

Comment: Yeah, that's why after reading the linked Q, I got confused and asked this Q.. @Rickross

Comment: I doubt that blog. Tulasi leaves are forbidden in Ganesh Puja.

Comment: The author says to use 21 names in the pushpa archana part of the puja. But usually 108 names are used.  Which 108 leaves to be used then? Actually they use either flowers or Durva grass. The author also mentions the source of information " I have followed the text published by TTD book "sacred plants:" What is TTD here?

Comment: Quick Google search suggests TTD: Tirumala Tirupati Devasthanam..

Comment: Hmm .. thanks ..

Comment: I do lack scripture, but we offer Tulasi only once during Ganesha festival on the first day during the vidhi of pran-prathista. No other times its offered.